# Gravity Forms - Enqueue JS when form embedded?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I want to be able to only enqueue certain JavaScript when there is a form embedded (emedded with shortcode and php).

Is there an action hook for Gravity Forms that triggers when a form is embedded? Then I could do something like this.

```
add_action('some_gforms_hook', function() {
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'postcode', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/modules/Postcode/assets/js/postcode.js', array('jquery') );
        wp_localize_script( 'postcode', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
    });
});
```

If there is no such hook, is there another (non hacky) way of archiving what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this example in the documentation.

```
add_action( 'gform_register_init_scripts', 'gform_format_money' );
function gform_format_money( $form ) {

    $script = '(function($){' .
        '$('.gf_money input').each(function(){' .
            '$(this).val(gformFormatMoney($(this).val()));' .
        '}).change(function(){' .
            '$(this).val(gformFormatMoney($(this).val()));' .
        '});' .
    '})(jQuery);';

    GFFormDisplay::add_init_script( $form['id'], 'format_money', GFFormDisplay::ON_PAGE_RENDER, $script );
}
```

The problem with this example is that I don't like the JS written in my PHP files and the `add_init_script()` function needs a string with JS as argument.

I could use `file_get_contents()` to get the JS from the file but then I will not be able to localize the script for injecting the AJAX url.

I now use the hook as in the question and it works perfect.

```
add_action( 'gform_register_init_scripts', function() {
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'postcode', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/modules/Postcode/assets/js/postcode.js', array('jquery') );
        wp_localize_script( 'postcode', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [gform_enqueue_scripts](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_enqueue_scripts/). It passes the `$form` object so you determine if your scripts should be loaded for the given form.